# Kriging (or other interpolation) with integral constraints?

Tags: interpolation, kriging

I would like to interpolate a continuous variable (from observed point locations) on a surface (gridded) but using an external constraint that the cumulative distribution function of the interpolated values should match some known curve (not determined by the distribution of observed points).

Is there some variation of Kriging or other interpolation method (maybe GWR) that can achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean for a set of N observations, i=1 to N, {(x_i,y_i)} and a set of M interpolation locations j=1 to M {x_j} compute the set {(x_j, y_j)} where the set makes an "interpolation" (in some sense) of {(x_i, y_i)} *and* that the set {y_j} matches some arbitrary distribution? Does the set {y_i} match that distribution? Because if it doesn't, you can't satisfy both conditions if {x_j}=={x_i} and your interpolator is a true interpolator. There's too much constraint here or your description isn't clear enough...

Comment: The constraint is not explicitly spatial so we are just interpolating {x_i} to {x_j} subject to some distribution of values p(x). It is true that the constraint may not be able to be satisfied exactly depending on the distribution of {x_i}. I'm hoping there is a method to jointly minimize the interpolation error and deviation from satisfying the constraint. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thinking in one dimension for a moment, suppose your data are measured at x_i={0,1, 2}, and have values of y_i={0, 1, 0} (so the graph looks like a triangle `/\\`). Can you give an example of a "known curve" for the resulting distribution function of the interpolated values? How would an interpolator then satisfy that for predictions at a set of locations 0 from 2 in steps of 0.1, say? If you can edit your question for clarity that would be best.